# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.by' has no attribute 'XPATH' using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm starting in programming, so I created a simple code, but it's giving this error:

[image]

I'm using Jupyter Notebook, this is the code, if anyone knows what the problem is, please help me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error already tells you, `by.XPATH` doesn't exist. But `by` has a class called `By` and it's attribute `XPATH`.

Like that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = ...
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "YOUR_XPATH")
```

Answer (score 1):

*XPATH* and other [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) are implemented through the [**By**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) implementation:

```
"""
The By implementation.
"""


class By(object):
    """
    Set of supported locator strategies.
    """

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

So essentially you have to import **By** from *`selenium.webdriver.common.by`*. Hence, the import statement should have been:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

and then you can use:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="i0116"]').send_keys("TESTE")
```